# google api translate java

Tags: java

I am using google-api-translate-java-0.95.jar.to translate a set of terms writing in french  towards English ,but I have this error  the program run correctly but At the moment look it give me this error
please why ?

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Google returned the following    error: [403] Suspected Terms of Service Abuse. Please see <http://code.google.com/apis/errors>
    at com.google.api.translate.Translate.getJSONResponse(Translate.java:182)
    at com.google.api.translate.Translate.execute(Translate.java:71)
    at translate.main(translate.java:72)
     Java Result: 1
```

thanks  in advance

Comment: did you try to read that link to Google's api errors?

Answer (score 2):

It's because you've been blocked or throttled. See the link in that URL: [API access notice](http://code.google.com/apis/errors/)

> You received this notice because Google has blocked or throttled this website's access to the Google API.

See that link for details about when that happens and what you can do about it.

Comment: hi , Is what that is no problem of the number of terms has to translate?